# img inside table row with tr width

Tags: html, css

How can I do this with CSS?

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ou8sdfLo/

I want to put an `<img>` inside a `<tr>` with a widh equal to its `<tr>`.

I hope it is clear enough.

I modified the image to match the code.

Answer (score 1):

The image needs to be in a `td`, and if you want that `td` to span the entire width of the `tr` use the `colspan` attribute. Then if you want the `img` to fill the width of the `td`, use `display: block; width: 100%;`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background: #888;
  color: white;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Max speed</th>
    <th>Power</th>
    <th>Swept volume</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Car 1</td>
    <td>45 mph (72 km/h)</td>
    <td>22 hp</td>
    <td>2865 ccm</td>
    <td>800 kg</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="car_preview"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Car 2</td>
    <td>45 mph (72 km/h)</td>
    <td>22 hp</td>
    <td>2865 ccm</td>
    <td>800 kg</td>
  </tr>

  </table
```

Comment: ok but what if I want the <img> to be in the same <tr> of "Car 1"?

Comment: @Champop then you might consider not using a table or asking yourself why it has to be in the same `tr` and if you can do it without that requirement. You can't have an `img` as a direct child of a `tr` - it has to be in a `td`. And a `td` in a table will display adjacent to other `td`'s. You're stretching the limits of a `table`. You should be able to pull of whatever it is you want to do visually without having the `img` in the same `tr`

Answer (score 0):

The only valid tag within a `<tr>` is `<td>`. 
In the `<img>` row, you would need to set a `colspan` on your `<td>` equal to the total number of columns.

Like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="6"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
```